# Slide out Side menu not Navigating to scrolling Anchor links on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navigation, anchor

So I am having this issue with my HTML site found here: http://graphicallyill.com/

The issue happens on mobile, while tablet, laptop and desktop all scroll to the desired anchor point on the site when clicking on any of the side menu links, on mobile sizes the menu links do not navigate anywhere they just seem to close the menu and the user stays stuck at the top of the page.

Ideally when the link in the menu is clicked it would hide the side menu off screen and then scroll nicely down to the desired sections anchor tag.

Can anyone see any issues with this as I cannot for the life of me find out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when the width becomes mobile-size the first div with id `#store` gets `display:none` property so the window can't scroll to something "that isn't there".

The solution could be making only one div with `#store`.